# MSSQL injection help

Tags: sql-injection, databases

If information_schema is not allowed in MSSQL , what is another method i can use to list the tables inside a database and ultimately the columns so i can dump them without using information_schema?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the sqlmap project? http://sqlmap.org It is written in python and they have an api you can use. It is open source too.  It is really a great tool and eliminates a lot of the busy work involved with exploiting a sql injection vulnerability

Comment: Also this cheat sheet is great: http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mssql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

Comment: @735Tesla sqlmap isn't advanced enough to exploit this one. I tried it and it failed, hard.

Comment: Oh well it was worth a try, did you try the example pentestmonkey gave? I don't think that involved information_schema

Comment: If worst comes to worst you could try brute forcing table names

Answer (score 1):

> If information_schema is not allowed in MSSQL, what is another method i can use to list the tables inside a database and ultimately the columns so i can dump them without using information_schema? Thanks.

For SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'
SELECT name FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type = 'U'
SELECT name FROM sys.columns
SELECT name FROM sys.all_columns
SELECT t.name, c.name FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c
SELECT * FROM TableGuess1
SELECT * FROM TableGuess2
SELECT * FROM TableGuess3
SELECT * FROM TableGuess4
```

BACKUP DATABASE ... and collect the backup.

You can also try the information from @735tesla's [MSSQL injection cheat sheet](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mssql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet), in his comment to the question above, but be aware that's SQL 2000 syntax (which is still supported for backwards compatibility in many later versions).

Comment: Dude why does convert(int,(select name from sys.columns)) cause: Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.? All the rest of those commands create similar errors.

Comment: Convert a variable or column, not a query.  select convert(int, name) from sys.columns

Comment: Doesn't work man. Same error :(.

Comment: Load up MS SQL Server Express on your machine, and try the raw SQL there to make sure the syntax works first.